# Are there any potential issues that can arise from implementing pam_faillock into Debian's default PAM configuration

Tags: debian, pam

I'm working on setting up a multi-user Debian server that thin-clients connect to via VNC tunneled over SSH. The setup itself isn't really anything sophisticated. In the effort of implementing a few common-sense security best practices, we want to setup automatic account lockout after consecutive authentication failures. This is my first exposure to making configuration changes to PAM so I am very much a PAM novice. From the research I've done so far to figure out the best way to implement this automatic account lockout, it seems that there are really two PAM modules that directly serve this purpose: `pam_tally2.so` and `pam_faillock.so`. Having already had some exposure to working with faillock on RHEL and Fedora, that was the route we ultimately decided to go. Debian's PAM configuration is very different from RHEL/ Fedora's, so it took a bit of research, but this is ultimately what we came up with:

**Modified `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`**

```
# Added faillock preauth
auth    required                        pam_faillock.so preauth
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
# auth  requisite                       pam_deny.so
# replace the default line commented above, but send the same signal
auth    [default=die]                   pam_faillock.so authfail
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**Modified `/etc/pam.d/common-account`**

```
# reset the fail record on authentication success
account required                        pam_faillock.so
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

In the preliminary testing that has be done so far, this seems to work exactly as intended. Are there any potential "gotchas" that we're overlooking here? It seems like `pam_tally2.so` is typically the default recommendation to serve this purpose on Debian. This combined with the lack of references for implementing `pam_faillock.so` on any distributions outside of RHEL and Fedora as well as my lack of experience with PAM configuration has made us a bit nervous that we're overlooking something with the logic of this PAM stack configuration.